# HTTP request for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, httprequest

I am having trouble making a http request inside a loop.

I can get the values I need but they are not always in the same order.

Here is my code:

```
async function test(){
 for (let k = 0; k < ids.length; k++) {

   var ids1 = ids[k]
   GetMyResourceData(ids1)
  
    console.log(ids1)
}
}
 function  GetMyResourceData(current){
  
    var requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                redirect: 'follow'
                };
  fetch( "url" + current , requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(result => {
                    var res = JSON.parse(result)
        console.log(res[0].regular_price)
          
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
   
}
test()
```

The output for 5 items comes like this :

5.25 ,
19.55 ,
13.55 ,
8.25 ,
22.82,

and sometimes like this :

5.25 ,
13.55 ,
19.55 ,
22.82 ,
8.25 ,

I have tried everything, this async was my last shot :D

Does anyone know what I can do to get the data always in order that comes from the loop?

That would be life saving ;)

Thanks!!!

Comment: in your `GetMyResourceData` inside your loop use the `away` keyword

Answer (score 0):

The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) requests are asynchronous meaning they will not honor you order of execution because of the variations in time of completion.

Instead of logging each individual request, make sure that the `GetMyResourceData` returns the `fetch` request and pushes it into an array of requests, so that all requests are in a single array.

Then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for *all* the requests to finish. Now you'll have an array of responses in the order in which the requests were called.

Also note, that the `response` from the request can parse JSON with the [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method.

```
function test() {
  let requests = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < ids.length; k++) {
    let ids1 = ids[k]
    requests.push(GetMyResourceData(ids1))
  }
  return Promise.all(requests);
}


function GetMyResourceData(current) {
  let requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  return fetch("url" + current, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}

test().then(responses => {
  responses.forEach(res => {
    console.log(res[0].regular_price)
  });
});
```

Comment: `const requests = ids.map(GetMyResourceData)`